# What is the datatype for a file column in database

Tags: mysql, reactjs, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file using React JS.
I created a form to enter a partner's name and its logo.

This is what I get when I submit the form and console.log :

> {partnername: "Google", partnerlogoimage: File}
> partnerlogoimage: File
> lastModified: 1603793235562
> lastModifiedDate: Tue Oct 27 2020 11:07:15 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
> name: "google2.0.0.jpg"
> size: 28626
> type: "image/jpeg"
> webkitRelativePath: ""
> **proto**: File
> partnername: "Google"

What is the type of the "partnerlogoimage" column that I should choose in the database?

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use it "image" in SQL SERVER database

but if you asking it on model ;
public byte[] FILE { get; set; }
you can use it like this.

Comment: "public byte[]" — What makes you think Java is involved?